# django nginx uwsgi not working

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

i ve created a django application not using virtual environment. I ve installed nginx and trying to integrate them via uwsgi application.
Here my configurations files.

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti
wsgi-file = ES_Brevetti/wsgi.py
master = true
processes = 5
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
socket = unix:///socket/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

i've created the file /sockect/uwsgi.sock with permission 777

chown nginx:nginx -R /sockect/uwsgi.sock

and below nginx conf file:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///socket/uwsgi.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.184.2.231;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static/ { 
        alias /home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///socket/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

When i launch "systemctl start nginx" nginx is started with error:
 connect() to unix:///socket/uwsgi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,

When i run uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/ES_Brevetti.ini  it doesnt run with error:

```
.....
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]
```

What i am doing wrong? On google i can only see configurations with VENV while i am not using virtual environment.

Comment: Now uwsgi is up and running but keep on receiving the following error : 502 Bad Gateway and on nginx log file i get "connect() to unix:///socket/uwsgi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream". Any help please?

Comment: You say running uwsgi doesn't run with an error, but the output shows an error `bind(): Permission denied`, which looks the same as your `111: Connection refused` error. This suggests your socket doesn't have the right ownership / permissions. Can you show the permissions of the socket and say what user you are running everything as?

Comment: Ok and thanx for ur reply . My socket permission for uwsgi.sock is 777 and the owner is nginx:nginx   the nginx server is started as root:  "sudo systemctl start nginx" otherwise it wouldnt start, while uwsgi is run as user "elastic" that is the user i am logged in but in the ini file i have uid = nginx
gid = nginx  ....any help?  btw i ve added nginx

Comment: btw i have also : sudo usermod -a -G elastic nginx
chmod 710 /home/elastic

Comment: I dont have any longer Permission denied but i still do have 111: Connection refused anytime i start nginx. Where this error comes from ?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) (which I'm guessing you were following) suggest that the `socket` configuration option in your uwsgi ini file should take a path to the socket, not a URL. Could you try changing:

```
[uwsgi]
...
socket = unix:///socket/uwsgi.sock
```

to

```
[uwsgi]
...
socket = /socket/uwsgi.sock
```

Comment: If i make that change i get again the error when running uwsgi: error removing unix socket, unlink(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 198]
bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 230]

Answer (score -1):

The solution was change the socket = unix:///socket/uwsgi.sock to socket = /socket/uwsgi.sock in the uwsgi.ini file. I dont know why in some doc it appears the double slash for escaping.